# Extract key value from a nested object in js

Tags: javascript, object

How should I extract key from a nested object If i enter Mumbai , I want to get Maharashtra and India.If The user will enter value like 'Dallas', then it should return Texas and USA

```
obj = {
       "India":
          {
            "Karnataka": ["Bangalore", "Mysore"],
            "Maharashtra": ["Mumbai", "Pune"]
          },
      "USA": 
          {
           "Texas": ["Dallas", "Houston"],
           "IL": ["Chicago", "Aurora", "Pune"]
          }
      }
```

Comment: Someone asked a similar question, just with "Pune" - was that you?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62860095/how-to-search-for-a-value-in-object-which-contains-sub-objects-with-as-array-val

Comment: You have accepted an answer that doesn't work (at time of this comment).  
Try using it looking for "Pune".  
Also, it's not very re-usable - functions are better - see other's and my answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the object and find the respective keys by matching the value:

```js
var obj = {
       "India":
          {
            "Karnataka": ["Bangalore", "Mysore"],
            "Maharashtra": ["Mumbai", "Pune"]
          },
      "USA": 
          {
           "Texas": ["Dallas", "Houston"],
           "IL": ["Chicago", "Aurora", "Pune"]
          }
      }
var country, state;
var city = 'Mumbai';

for(var k in obj){
  for(var j in obj[k]){
    if(obj[k][j].includes(city)){
      country = k;
      state = j;
    }
  }
}
console.log(country + ', ' + state);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** After rereading the question and comments from @iAmOren.

Let's recurse through the tree. This will work for any tree depth. It will also find a State or a Country (or in other words, any key or value at any level).

**Edit 2:** Thanks for the feedback again, @iAmOren. Now, it finds all instead of "find first" in my last solution.

```js
var obj = {
       "India":
          {
            "Karnataka": ["Bangalore", "Mysore", "Texas"],
            "Maharashtra": ["Mumbai", "Pune"]
          },
      "USA": 
          {
           "Texas": ["Dallas", "Houston"],
           "IL": ["Chicago", "Aurora", "Pune"]
          }
      };


var getParents = function(o, toFind, found, path) {
  if (path === undefined) path = [];
  for(var key in o) {
    // Matches city or the parent nodes (country or state).
    if (o[key] === toFind || key === toFind) {
      var aFoundPath = Object.assign([], path);
      aFoundPath.push(toFind);
      found.push(aFoundPath);
    }
    else {
      if (typeof o[key] == "object") {
        path.push(key);
        getParents(o[key], toFind, found, path);
        path.pop();
      }
    }
  }
};

var printParents = function(toFind) {
  var outFound = [];
  getParents(obj, toFind, outFound);
  console.log(outFound);
};

printParents("Mumbai");
printParents("Pune");
printParents("Texas");
```

Comment: I think, perhaps, the OP wants a general way = input can be anything.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the question to me. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Very nice!  You are returning a "stack" of parents!  
However, `console.log(getParents(obj, "Pune"));` only returns `["Maharashtra", "India"]` - what about "IL, USA"?

Comment: I put 4 test values, on the bottom. Chicago => returned IL, USA

Comment: Sudip, look into searching for "Pune" - as in my last comment...  
Also, see my answer - a different approach.

Comment: Oh got it. What if a City name was in multiple countries or states. I have updated my solution to find all. Thank you for your feedback, @iAmOren

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer from a (very) similar question.
It returns an array of array of country and state.

```
function findCity(city) {
  var result=[];
  for(country in obj) {
    for(state in obj[country]) {
      if(obj[country][state].includes(city)) {
        result.push([country, state]);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

---

Note to possible down-voters:
Please explain why in detail instead.
Don't be a troll.
Thank you!